# Progress Bar in revolution slider WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

I found code to make my Progress Bar look like i need from this [source](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/progress-bar-slots-example/) . Everything work fine as expected. But i need to make  entire Progress Bar width 50% off main page. I try to add all `span` in one `div` and make this `div` 50-60% width but this didn't help. Need some help with that, thanks

Comment: Can you maybe share some code please? And to be clear, you want the progress bar (spans) all together 50% of the slider's width?

Comment: yes that correct all spans together be 50% of the slider's width.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuerys function .wrapAll() to wrap the span elements in a parent container. Give that new container a class and set position to absolute, left offset to 25% and right offset to 25%.

// JS

```
api.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

    var totalSlides = api.revmaxslide(),
        perc = parseFloat((100 / totalSlides).toFixed(2));

    for(var i = 0; i < totalSlides; i++) {

        progressSlots[i] = jQuery(
            '<span class="rev-progress-perc" ' + 
                  'style="width: ' + perc + '%; left: ' + (perc * i) + '%" ' + 
                  'data-slide="' + i + '" ' + 
            '/>'
        );

    }

    progressSlots.wrapAll('slots-wrapper');

    api.append(progressSlots);
    progressBar = jQuery('.tp-bannertimer');
    progressSlots = jQuery('.rev-progress-perc').on('click', changeSlides);

})
...
```

// CSS

```
.slots-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%; right: 25%;
}
```

Comment: no sorry this isnt work just brake the code and make Progress Bar appear in single slide one by one.

Comment: Can you try adding z-index to the wrapper?

Comment: sure i try but dont help sory.

Comment: That's why it's complicated to answer questions that are totally unclear and based on external code instead of a [mcve] @frederik The question has a high probability of being deleted automatically by the system throwing your efforts through the window :(

Comment: @brasofilo yea well there is some code in the link provided, I tried....